# PostgreSql does not "recognize" table created by Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, join

I have problem to create two associated tables with hibernate in a PostgreSQL database. I am inclined to believe that the problem lies in the Database (configuration?) since I have tried nearly all the Hibernate approaches proposed in Internet sites and I receive still the same error. Is there any configuration demanded before using a PostgreSql database? I cannot explain in other way the error which appears:

"Relation department does not exist"

I Join the two Entities Employee and Department as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="employee_id")
private Long employeeId;
.
.
.

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

private Department department;
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")
public class Department implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
private Long departmentId;

.
.
.
@OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}


private Set<Employee> employees;
```

I am trying to create the tables with a couple of records in the main method as:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Department department = new Department();
        department.setDepartmentName("Sales");
        session.persist(department);

        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Nina", "Mayers", "111");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Tony", "Almeida", "222");

        emp1.setDepartment(department);
        emp2.setDepartment(department);

        session.persist(emp1);
        session.persist(emp2);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

The error comes up on the line : `session.persist(department);`

Is anyone experienced in PostgreSql Databases, to help me to find why it cannot recognize the tables/relations and it comes up with the error:

"Relation department does not exist"  ?

**UPDATE:**

I have looked at the log file. After the usual message coming out from Eclipse as well, the last line of the message is: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". I deduce that the problem is probably at the connection. Are there any properties, which I should set (in pgAdmin) in order to achieve the connection? I have set the line

`<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDB</property>` in cfg.xml file in Eclipse.

Comment: Most like this is case folding. Unquoted identifiers are folded to lower case. Many access libs auto-quote for you, while things like psql do not.

Comment: Can you clarify your comment and make your suggestion what could be done? I cannot catch it as you express it. Thanks.

Comment: You have both `"DEPARTMENT"` and `"department"`, they probably should both have the same case.

Comment: @muistooshort: I have tried to write all either lower or upper case, but it does not change anything. Unfortunately this obvious case does not eliminate the problem.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe is almost certainly right - it is case folding. Your badly designed ORM is double-quoting all your identifiers meaning "DEPARTMENT" is different than "Department" or "department". It is also failing to give you any errors if you have a typo in your identifier names. Turn statement logging on in PostgreSQL if you don't believe him/me. Then, I'm afraid you've got a lot of tedious code search/replace to track down and check all your identifier problems.

Comment: @RichardHuxton: Isn't "badly designed ORM" a bit redundant? I've never used an ORM that wasn't terrible in some way, including all the ORMs I've built myself :)

Comment: @muistooshort - they're all bad, I'm not convinced they've all gone through something I'd call "design" though :-)

Comment: @RichardHuxton: Can you see my update? Have you any idea why it cannot establish the connection?

Comment: Did you verify that the table actually exists? What does `\d` in psql show you?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The table does not exist in advance. I want the Hibernate to create it. I am not quite familiar with PostgreSql. Can you explain in more detail how I check if the table exists through psql? The just noticed, that even if I remove the property "create" from cfg.xml (I keep the drop), it tries to insert values in department, without first dropping the existing table (I have created one manually in PgAdmin, just to ensure myself it works).

Comment: As I said, use the `\d` command in psql (for details see the manual). Sorry I don't know Hibernate (and I think that it's a bad idea to let the ORM create your database. You should have a proper, version controlled SQL script for this, e.g. using Liquibase)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate does not create Table in the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638930/hibernate-does-not-create-table-in-the-database)

Answer (score 1):

Start `psql your_database` and issue `\d` to see the tables.

I'm unfamiliar with Hibernate, but chances are that statements such as `@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")` are creating tables that are actually called `"DEPARTMENT"`, while your queries are actually querying from `DEPARTMENT` (without the double quotes), which postgresql will interpret as `department`.

If so, the fix is to either use lowercase for your table names when creating them, or to make Hibernate use double-quotes and caps when querying your tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you also have connection issues, the procedure to tackle those is what you would expect.

1. Check the postgreSQL server is running
2. Check you can connect via psql/pgAdmin
3. Check the connection settings in your application are the same as you used in step 2
4. Check the return codes of your connection call
5. Turn on connection logging in PostgreSQL and see if you get (a) an attempt and (b) an error
6. Simplify your code to find out where your error is.

A surprising amount of the time #1 or #3 are the cause, and presumably you aren't doing #4 or you'd not have bothered asking about the other error.